# Typescript declaration file is not a module

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try to create a typescript declaration file for a sample JS library

my_lib.js :

```
function f1(a, b) {
  return a + b;
} 
function f2(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}  
module.exports = {
  f1: f1,
  f2: f2 
}
```

my_lib.d.ts

```
declare module 'my_lib' {
    function f1(a: number, b: number): number;
    function f2(a: number, b: number): number;   
    export default {
        f1: f1,
        f2: f2 
    }
}
```

A typescript file try to used the library with

```
import my_lib from 'my_lib';
```

I have this error

> error TS2656: Exported external package typings file
>   'C:/.../my_lib.d.ts'
>   is not a module. Please contact the package author to update the
>   package definition.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**lib.d.ts** is a reserved filename for TypeScript internal library. Do not use it.

Comment: Ok, it was just a example, my real file is not the same. I update my post.

Comment: I'm using TypeScript 2.0.0 (beta), and I encounter no error. Maybe you could give a try to this new release (`npm install typescript@beta -g`).

Answer (score 1):

I solved using `export =` and `import my_lib = require("my_lib");` syntax